# Force CherryPy Child Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, cherrypy

Well, I want cherrypy to kill all child threads on auto-reload instead of  "Waiting for child threads to terminate" because my program has threads of its own and I don't know how to get past this. CherryPy keeps hanging on that one line and I don't know what to do to get the 'child threads' to terminate...

`

```
[05/Jan/2010:01:14:24] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080)) shut down
[05/Jan/2010:01:14:24] ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
[05/Jan/2010:01:14:24] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
[05/Jan/2010:01:14:24] ENGINE Bus EXITING
[05/Jan/2010:01:14:24] ENGINE Bus EXITED
[05/Jan/2010:01:14:05] ENGINE Waiting for child threads to terminate...
```

`

it never continues.. So i want to force the child threads to close ...

I know it is because my application is using threads of its own and I guess cherrypy wants those threads to quit along with CherryPy's.... Can I overcome this ?

Comment: I'm starting to think I should overload CherryPy's auto-reload to kill my own client.thread... But how, i dont kno.

Answer (score 14):

You need to write code that stops your threads, and register it as a listener for the 'stop' event:

```
from cherrypy.process import plugins

class MyFeature(plugins.SimplePlugin):
    """A feature that does something."""

    def start(self):
        self.bus.log("Starting my feature")
        self.threads = mylib.start_new_threads()

    def stop(self):
        self.bus.log("Stopping my feature.")
        for t in self.threads:
            mylib.stop_thread(t)
            t.join()

my_feature = MyFeature(cherrypy.engine)
my_feature.subscribe()
```

See http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/BuiltinPlugins and http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CustomPlugins for more details.

Comment: Okay. I will look into this. I'm using the quickstart method. Can  I put these start and stop methods inside my root class that I use with cherrypy.quickstart() ? Or can you tell me how I would use this class MyFeature(), with my already root class I'm using Root()..  Sorry, I haven't had extensive use with CherryPy..

Comment: Sure; you can put that code anywhere you like; the only important thing is that you subscribe it before you run quickstart.

Answer (score 0):

This works with quickstart

```
def stopit():
    print 'stop handler invoked'
    #...
stopit.priority = 10
cherrypy.engine.subscribe('stop', stopit)
```

> In order to support its life-cycle, CherryPy defines a set of common
>   channels that will be published to at various states:
>
> “start”: When the bus is in the “STARTING” state
>
> “main”: Periodically from the CherryPy’s mainloop
>
> **“stop”: When the bus is in the “STOPPING” state**
>
> “graceful”: When the bus requests a reload of subscribers
>
> “exit”: When the bus is in the “EXITING” state
>
> This channel will be published to by the engine automatically.
>   Register therefore any subscribers that would need to react to the
>   transition changes of the engine.

..

> In order to work with the bus, the implementation provides the
>   following simple API:
>
> cherrypy.engine.publish(channel, *args):
>
> The channel parameter is a string identifying the channel to which the
>   message should be sent to
>
> *args is the message and may contain any valid Python values or objects.
>
> **cherrypy.engine.subscribe(channel, callable)**:
>
> The channel parameter is a string identifying the channel the callable
>   will be registered to.
>
> callable is a Python function or method which signature must match
>   what will be published.

Comment: Why was this down-voted? This is recommended by cherrypi docs too.

https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/extend.html#built-in-channels

Couldn't find info on the priority field though.